# Flatlist re-renders on every scroll

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

anyone know why the flatlist keeps re-rendering on each scroll? I tried  converting my item to a pure component but it didnt work. out of ideas now. I get a warning:

`VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. {"contentLength": 5105.45458984375, "dt": 3337, "prevDt": 796}`

```
import React, { useRef, PureComponent } from "react";
import { View, Text, Image, FlatList, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import data from './testData'

class Item extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const {content, index} = this.props
    return (  
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.contentTitle}>{content.title}</Text>
          <View style={styles.contentTextContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.contentText}>{(content.castList)}</Text>
            {content.genres && content.genres.length > 0 ? <Text style={styles.contentText}>{content.genres}</Text> : null}
            <Text style={styles.contentText}>{(content.releaseDate)}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
      )
  }
}

const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
  console.log(index)
  return <Item content={item} index={index}  />
}

const Swiper = props => {
  const flatList = useRef()

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {props.header ? <AppText style={styles.header} text={props.header} /> : null}
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        horizontal
        pagingEnabled
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        ref={flatList}
      />
    </View>
  )  
}
```

As you can see from the console.log() in the renderItem, everytime i swipe it re-renders the entire flatlist

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is description of **FlatList** [optimizing](https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration).

Did you try **FlatList** props like these:

1. `maxToRenderPerBatch` with `windowSize`
2. `initialNumToRender`